# How would you reduce a json value

Tags: json, graphql

I have a Graphql returning values that look like this

`"{\"date\":\"2020-05-21\",\"time\":null,\"changed_at\":\"2020-05-25T16:16:33.201Z\"}"`

How would you target just the date to return "2020-05-21"?

Here is a larger picture of the retuned.

```
"column_values": [
          {
            "value": null,
            "id": "check8",
            "title": "Approved?"
          },
          {
            "value": "{\"date\":\"2020-05-21\",\"time\":null,\"changed_at\":\"2020-05-25T16:16:33.201Z\"}",
            "id": "due_date2",
            "title": "Due Date"
          },
          {
            "value": null,
            "id": "qtr",
            "title": "QTR"
          },
          {
            "value": null,
            "id": "status5",
            "title": "Priority"
          },
          {
            "value": "{\"index\":2,\"post_id\":null,\"changed_at\":\"2020-05-22T17:56:59.936Z\"}",
            "id": "status",
            "title": "Status"
          },
          {
            "value": null,
            "id": "progress",
            "title": "Progress"
          },
          {
            "value": null,
            "id": "link",
            "title": "Video Link"
          },
          {
            "value": null,
            "id": "formula8",
            "title": "DATE_API"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Do you have to parse the JSON or Stringify it first? perhaps Graphql isn't returning usable json. Thank you for any help or bump in the correct direction.

Comment: Depending on the language you are using. If you were to use nodejs, you could actually require directly keys from a json file. In other languages you may have to parse the json before you can properly understand it. GraphQL itself is not more than a spec, you should tell us in what language you are implementing this.

Comment: using which language? js?

Comment: you should have graphql response specs/types definitions for this api - probably `value` property is typed as `json` - just parse it

Comment: @TheFool Thank you, yes, I would be using nodejs. however unsure which function to run on the returned value to reduce to the characters inside the value. seems to me like they should be separated into just date, and then date changed_at, etc.

Comment: to all, thank you! and yes, I'll be using nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()` is the method used to generate a JSON string. If you apply it to something that's *already* a JSON string then you'll get a *double-encoded* JSON string.

What you need to use is the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
const jsonObject= '{"foo": "bar"}';
const decoded = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
console.log(decode, typeof decoded);
```

Result:

```
{ foo: 'bar' } 'object'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yes! I can see how this will be useful. I was able to reduce it to a date.  Now I have to figure out how to reduce and return cleaner json. basically {"name": "items name", "date" :"2020-05-21"} with some kind of for each loop. I'm one step closer thanks to you!